# How to update a JSON object value in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, angular

My Javascript is interacting with the following 2 JSON files:

readers.json:

```
[
    {
    "readerID": 1,
    "name": "Maria",
    "weeklyReadingGoal": 350,
    "totalMinutesRead": 5600,
    "bookID": 65
    },
    {
    "readerID": 2,
    "name": "Daniel",
    "weeklyReadingGoal": 210,
    "totalMinutesRead": 3000,
    "bookID": 65
    }
]
```

Books.json

```
[
    {
    "bookID": 65,
    "title": "Goodnight Moon",
    "author": "Margaret Wise Brown",
    "publicationYear": "1953"
    },
    {
    "bookID": 75,
    "title": "Winnie-the-Pooh",
    "author": "A. A. Milne",
    "publicationYear": "1926"
    }
]
```

At the moment, I am able to DELETE a book from *book.json*

When I delete a book, & that book's bookID exists in a *reader.json* object, I want to update that ID to 0.

For example, if I delete a book where bookID = 65, I want to change all the bookID's that are equal to 65 in *reader.json* to null.

Below is my code, I can provide additional code if required:

Books.js:

```
var data = getBookData();

var pos = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.bookID;
}).indexOf(parseInt(req.params.id, 10));

if (pos > -1) {
  data.splice(pos, 1);
} else {
  res.sendStatus(404);
}

saveBookData(data);

var readerData = getReaderData();
var bookID = req.params.id;
console.log('BOOK ID - ' + bookID); // prints: BOOK ID - 47
readerData.forEach(function (x) {
  if (x.bookID === bookID) {
    x.bookID = null;
  }
  else {
    console.log('Deleted book was not associated with any reader');
    console.log('BOOK ID in else - ' + x.bookID); // prints: BOOK ID in else - 47
  }
});

saveReaderData(readerData);
res.sendStatus(204);
});

function getReaderData() {
    var data = fs.readFileSync(readerFile, 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

When I run this code, the book is removed from *books.json*, but the matching bookID's in *readers.json* are remaining the same.

Also, in the `else` block above, the matching bookID's are being logged, but for some reason the code is not flowing into the `if` block.

Comment: you want to replace each matching bookID to null ?

Comment: I want to loop through readers.json, & replace all matching bookID's within that JSON to null.

Comment: @AmitBaranes I've updated my `books.js` above to show how I'm getting the **bookID** & deleting it. I then want to loop through _readers.json_ & replace all matching bookID's within that to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on the readers and perform a check of the `bookID`. Is this what you wanted?

Your mistake is to use `indexOf` on an array, because it will returns only the first match to you.

```js
const readerData = [{
    "readerID": 1,
    "name": "Maria",
    "weeklyReadingGoal": 350,
    "totalMinutesRead": 5600,
    "bookID": 65,
  },
  {
    "readerID": 1,
    "name": "Maria",
    "weeklyReadingGoal": 350,
    "totalMinutesRead": 5600,
    "bookID": 70,
  },
  {
    "readerID": 2,
    "name": "Daniel",
    "weeklyReadingGoal": 210,
    "totalMinutesRead": 3000,
    "bookID": 65,
  },
];

const bookID = 65;

// Treat every reader
readerData.forEach((x) => {
  // If the bookID is the one we are looking for, set it as null
  if (x.bookID === bookID) {
    x.bookID = null;
  }
});

console.log(readerData);
```

---

So. Applied to your code

```
var readerFile = 'server/data/readers.json';

router.route('/')
  .delete(function(req, res) {
    var readerData = getReaderData();

    var bookID = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

    // Have we found any occurence of the bookID ?
    var found = false;

    // Treat every reader
    readerData.forEach(function(x) {
      // If the bookID is the one we are looking for, set it as null
      if (x.bookID === bookID) {
        x.bookID = null;

        found = true;
      }
    });

    // If we haven't found any occurence, returns an error
    if (!found) {
      res.sendStatus(404);

      return;
    }

    // Save the changes
    saveReaderData(readerData);

    res.sendStatus(204);
  });

function getReaderData() {
  var data = fs.readFileSync(readerFile, 'utf8');

  return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Comment: FYI. In case your userbase uses IE, arrow functions are not supported in IE -> https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Yeah, thanks you to point it out. I'm so used to it now. Just replace `() => {` by `function() {`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I want to check if the BookID of each reader matches the passed in BookID. If it does, then set the BookID of that Reader to null. Your `forEach` above, which piece of my code to I replace that with?

Comment: I've edited my post. Please takes time to understand. Do not just copy paste it

Comment: I've merged your code with mine above, please take a look. Currently, it is deleting the book record from _books.json_ but now it isn't doing anything to reader records in _readers.json_ that have that same `BookID`

Comment: Also, in the `else` block above, I've logged the **x.bookID** & it matches the bookID that I have just deleted from _books.json_

Comment: I think that BookID is a string in your json, cast it to Number using ParseInt before to compare it